# Why ampersand should be escaped first in html escaping?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

Why similar escaping codes do not work for html escaping in html elements if ampersand is not escaped first? After I put &amp to the first place everything works.

```
  function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
            return unsafe
                 .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                 .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                 .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
                 .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
                .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: Think about it. If you're first replacing some characters **with an ampersand** and then afterwards **replace ampersands**... uhm...

Comment: Look at the other 4 items. What do they start with? What will happen if you replace `&` last?

Comment: Yes, I suspected this... But why downvotes? Too trivial a question is?

Comment: unfortunately yes @user3695711 I wouldn't personally downvote because what one feel is trivial, others feel a little research might have found the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider what happens:

```
This sentence has an <html> tag in it
```

If you do the `<>` replacements first, you end up with

```
This sentence has an &lt;html&gt; tag in it
```

Then you do the `&` replacement, and get

```
This sentence has an &amp;lt;html&amp;gt; tag in it
```

Now your `&lt;` and `&gt;` are corrupted because the `<>` characters have been double-encoded.

If you encode `&` first, things "Just work".